# Generate X.509 (non self signed) Client Certificate Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, security, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Is it possible to generate a client certificate on-the-fly in ASP.NET without using makecert.exe? the generated certificate should be signed with a given CA certificate (the specific CA certificate is saved on file system and selected at runtime). The generated certificate should be attached to a web request to another server in order to pull data.

The flow:

User asking for an ASP.NET page on IIS -> certificate is generated on IIS using ASP.NET -> calling another server with the certificate attached -> data is returned and is shown on the requested page for the user.

I couldn't find a way for doing natively through the .NET Framework and explored different options such as:

- CertEnroll.dll - This interface replaces the old IEnroll4 interface. It seems that it only supports a creation of a certificate request - IX509Enrollment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377809(v=VS.85).aspx
- Bouncy Castle - An open source project which I might not be able to use (license issues)

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Please explain your use case a bit better. Why would you want to generate certificates per request?

Comment: Did you actually read the [Bouncycastle license](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/licence.html)?

Comment: Doobi - Yes. I would like to generate certificates per request and maybe cache for the user on the IIS.
GregS - Currently I need to find some solution which doesn't involve 3rd party component if any...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [PKIBlackbox package](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php) of our SecureBlackbox components. They let you generate certificates, as well as perform numerous other PKI functions.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment, I'm searching for a non 3rd party solution and if not, a free open source one.

Comment: @soguy if you want pure managed solution, then you would have to write one yourself or use third-party library. Also as far as I know PKCS#10 (certificate requests) are supported only by SecureBlackbox.

Answer (score 0):

How about using OpenSSL? http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/